# css equal height div blocks

Tags: css

I have 3 blocks

[image]

```
<div>loremloremloremlorem</div>
<div>loremloremlorem</div>
<div>loremloremloremlorem</div>
```

How to set CSS to have aqual height ? I cant use `row`, because it's responsive design and I 1 row can be flexible count of items.

Comment: Place your code please.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking, in your example what height you want render? For each div should be the same?

Comment: can you place your css code please

Comment: Can you add CSS also.

Comment: see this example: http://codepen.io/micahgodbolt/pen/FgqLc - is JS solution

Comment: http://callmenick.com/post/css-equal-height-columns-three-different-ways

Answer (score 1):

Use `display:table` and `display:table-cell`.

```css
.container {
    display:table;
}

.item {
    display:table-cell;
    width:100px;
    border:2px solid black;
}

.item + .item {
    border-left:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="item">test test test test</div>
    <div class="item">test test test test test test test test test test test test</div>
    <div class="item">test test test test test test test test</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use flexbox: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

```css
div.container {
    display:flex;
}
div.item {
    border:1px solid #000;
    display:block;
    width:100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="item">lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem</div>
    <div class="item">lorem lorem lorem</div>
    <div class="item">lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem</div>  
</div>
```

Comment: This is the best solution! Using display:table like other people are suggesting is for TABLES. OP's problem is a great candidate for a Flexbox solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you can wrap them inside a container, you can set it `display:table` and assign `display:table-cell` to each inner DIV. In this way, blocks are treated as table cells and so, alla with equal height. Please look at this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9qmbns2k/)

**CSS**:

```
#wrapper
{
    display:table;
}

#wrapper div
{
    display:table-cell;
    border:solid 1px red;
    width:50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this, by using `display: table` in the container div, and use `display: table-cell` in children.

See my CodePen code:

http://codepen.io/michelgefuni/pen/YPeVxN